# Azure IoT Python SDK how to set content type on uploaded images

Tags: azure-iot-hub

Uploading an image via the Python SDK, the "Content Type" in Azure Blob storage is always "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

Certain applications, like Twilio, require a correct content type when accessing blob files, to render an MMS message.

I would like to request the ability to set the content Type at upload, vs. having to do it in code.

(For others) As a workaround, I am using the code below (include WindowsAzure.Storage from NuGet):

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

        static void ChangeContentType(string URI)
        {
            //Parse the connection string for the storage account.
            const string ConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=accountName;AccountKey=AccountKey";
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionString);

            //Create the service client object for credentialed access to the Blob service.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            ICloudBlob imageFile = blobClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServer(new Uri(URI));
            imageFile.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            imageFile.SetProperties();
        }
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, you can make a request for this capability by creating an issue here: https://github.com/azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/issues